# Magento AJAX newsletter submit when pressing enter

Tags: ajax, magento, newsletter

I am using code to submit newsletter info via AJAX through a submit button, but unfortunately when a user fills in their email address and presses enter the page simply reloads and no data is saved.

I would like a user pressing enter to get the same results as a user clicking the submit button. Thank you for any wisdom/guidance!

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="block block-subscribe">
    <div id="feedback" style="display:none" class="mini-newsletter">
    Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter! 
    </div>

    <form name="newsletter-form" id="newsletter-form" method="post"> 
        <div class="block-content">
         <div class="input-box">
          <input onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event,this.form)" type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to Our Newsletter') ?>" class="required-entry input-subscribe" style="width:178px;" />
          <div class="error-news-msg" id="error-news-msg" style="display:none;">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="news-loader" id="news-loader" style="text-align:center; display:none;">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/news-loader.gif'); ?>" />
            </div>    
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" onclick="myfunc();" class="button">
                 <span><span>Subscribe</span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
       </div>
    </form>    
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function myfunc()
        {    
            var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-form');
            var form_email = $('newsletter').getValue();
            var params_form = $('newsletter-validate-detail');
            //alert(params_form);
            new Validation('newsletter');
            if(echeck(form_email))
            {
            //alert(form_email);
            //alert(Form.serialize($('newsletter-validate-detail')));
            new Ajax.Updater({ success: 'newsletter-form' }, '<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new') ?>', {
                asynchronous:true, evalScripts:false,
                parameters: { email: form_email },
                onComplete:function(request, json){Element.hide('newsletter-form'); Element.hide('news-loader'); Element.show('feedback');},
                onLoading:function(request, json){Element.show('news-loader');},

            });



            }
            else
            {
            //alert(form_email);
                return false;
            }

        }    



function echeck(str) {

        var at="@"
        var dot="."
        var lat=str.indexOf(at)
        var lstr=str.length
        var ldot=str.indexOf(dot)
        if (str.indexOf(at)==-1){
           //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
           goProcedural()
           return false
        }

        if (str.indexOf(at)==-1 || str.indexOf(at)==0 || str.indexOf(at)==lstr){
           //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
           goProcedural()
           return false
        }

        if (str.indexOf(dot)==-1 || str.indexOf(dot)==0 || str.indexOf(dot)==lstr){
            //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            goProcedural()
            return false
        }

         if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1){
            //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            goProcedural()
            return false
         }

         if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot){
            //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            goProcedural()
            return false
         }

         if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1){
            //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            goProcedural()
            return false
         }

         if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
            //alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            goProcedural()
            return false
         }

          return true                    
    }

function goProcedural()
{
  Element.show('error-news-msg');
  Element.hide.delay(5, 'error-news-msg');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, good practice for code blocks is to put only the relevant HTML in one block and then the relevant JS in another.  If you don't include enough, you may be asked to expand it, but pasting in the entire source makes it less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work!

I changed:

```
<form name="newsletter-form" id="newsletter-form" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form name="newsletter-form" id="newsletter-form" method="post" onsubmit="myfunc(event)">
```

Then changed:

```
function myfunc()
```

To:

```
function myfunc(event)
```

Then changed:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" onclick="myfunc();" class="button">
```

To:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" onclick="myfunc(event)" class="button">
```

And then right before this line:

```
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-form');
```

I added this line:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a common issue and seems to be specific to Internet Explorer.

The problem is that the button click is submitting the form as well as firing the onclick event. These are two different events and the form submit seems to take precedence.

To fix this you need to put a `return false;` into the onclick call:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" onclick="myfunc(); return false;" class="button">
```

This will stop the click event submitting the form.

Comment: I must admit, I haven't seen Chrome do this. Have you tried the change to see if it works?

Comment: I do not see any effect from this change.

Answer (score 0):

Open : app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml

Create one backup of this file and replace it with this code.

```
<div class="awis-news-block">
<div class="ajax-newsletter-subscribe-form">
<form id="ajax_newsletter_subscribe_form" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email">
               <button id="ajax-newsletter-submit" class="button" type="submit" title="JOIN">.
                 <span><span>JOIN</span></span>
                </button>
<input type="hidden" class="url1" value="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>">
                <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Email Id.</span>
                <span class="valid" style="display:none"> Please enter a valid email address.To review our privacy policy, please click here.</span>
                <span class="success" style="display:none">Thank you for joining our email club. Check your email for your 15% off coupon!</span>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {        
        var email = $("#newsletter").val();
        var url1 = $(".url1").val();
        var dataString = 'email='+ email;

            if(email=='')
            {
                $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('.valid').fadeOut(200).hide();            

                $('.error').fadeIn(200).fadeOut(8000);

            }
            if (email!='')
            {

                var a = email;

                var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{1,4}$/;
                if(filter.test(a)){
                    ajaxn();
                }
                else{
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.valid').fadeIn(200).fadeOut(8000);
                }

            }
        function ajaxn()
            {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url1,
                data: dataString,
                success: function()
                    {                
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.valid').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).fadeOut(8000);

                    }
                });
            }   
        return false;
        });
    });

    </script>
```

For more information [submit magento newsletter using ajax](http://webdesignergeeks.com/cms/magento/submit-magento-newsletter-using-ajax/)